# How to Detect Security Mode of Wifi Access Point? (WEP/WPA/WPA2)

Tags: wireless

How can I find out what type of security a wireless access point (essid) is using? wep/wpa/wpa2 (preferably using commandline tools)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `iwlist` tool to print out all details of access points nearby. Assuming your wireless device is called `wlan0`:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

The output from iwlist will show each 'Cell' (or access point) that it finds, including the following details about the encryption type:

```
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

This indicates that a network near me is using WPA2, using a pre-shared key (PSK).

Comment: Why sudo?. You should be able to use iwlist as a normal user, at least I can in my computer.

Comment: From the iwlist manpage, "Triggering  scanning  is  a privileged operation (root only) and normal users can only read left-over scan results".

Answer (score 16):

**nmcli**  is command-line client for NetworkManager. It can be used to view security types of nearby wireless access points.

```
$> nmcli device wifi list
```

Result will show up as following:

[image: result image]

Comment: awesome - this rocks

Answer (score 4):

`NetworkManager` has a great command-line backend called `nmcli`. The small draw-back is that some commands in 15.04 differ from 14.04 version of `nmcli`.

**Ubuntu 14.04**

`nmcli  -f NAME con status` allows listing names of the current connections. For example,

```
$ nmcli -f NAME,DEVICES con status                                                                                                
NAME                      DEVICES   
Serg-Wifi                    wlan0
```

Now, to list specific details about a connection, we can do `nmcli con list id "WifiName"`. To be more specific, we are looking for line that says `key-mgmt`.

```
$ nmcli con list id "SergWifi" | awk '/key-mgmt/ {print $2}'                                                                        
wpa-psk
```

Thus we know , this wifi uses WPA protection.

Another hint is the following line:

```
802-11-wireless.security:               802-11-wireless-security
```

Now, how do we put this into the same script ?
If you have only one connection established ,

```
nmcli con list id "$(nmcli -t -f NAME con status)" | awk '/key-mgmt/||/802-11-wireless\.security/ {print $2}'
```

Here we merely manipulate `nmcli` with -t flag to give us only the name of wifi Access Point without the pretty header,and use it in parameter substitution brackets`$( . . .)` and give it as an input to  `nmcli con list id` to list data about that Access Point. Finally, `awk` just filters out the necessary line.

If you have wifi connection established but also Ethernet connected, `nmcli -f NAME con status` will output multiple lines. I suggest filtering out wifi from that list, with `nmcli -f NAME,DEVICES con status | awk '/wlan0/ {print $1}'`. The rest of the processing would be the same as above.

**Ubuntu 15.04**

The above commands translate in 15.04 as follows:

- `nmcli -t -f NAME,DEVICE con status | awk -F':' '/wlan0/{print }'` to get the name of established connection on `wlan0`
- `nmcli con show "ConnectionName"` to list details about your established connection.

**Side note:** in Ubuntu 14.04 there is `nm-tool` which lists information about your current connections in a readily organized format, however it is not present in 15.04 , hence I suggest you study and play with it on your own